# Get the count of each table

Tags: oracle

I was trying to create a procedure to fetch the total count of rows of all tables corresponding to a schema.
I am proceeding with a cursor which store the total list of tables and and the same is iterate further. Even though the functionality is not tested.The procedure creation compiled with the following errors.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE PROC_TABLE_COUNT
AS
  table_count NUMBER;
  CURSOR total_tables
  IS
     SELECT table_name FROM dba_tables WHERE owner = 'OWNER_NAME';
BEGIN
  FOR i IN total_tables
  LOOP
  SELECT COUNT (*) INTO table_count FROM dba_tables db where db.table_name = i.table_name;
  END LOOP;
END PROC_TABLE_COUNT;


1)Error(7,6): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2)Error(7,33): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
3)Error(11,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4)Error(11,76): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "I"."TABLE_NAME": invalid identifier
5)Error(11,76): PLS-00364: loop index variable 'I' use is invalid
```

Question 1:
Is the error 2(at `dba_tables`) is due to the grant being denied? By right clicking on the procedure name ,I tried to assign the privilege to debug and execute. But still the error persists.
Question 2:
Regarding the invalid identifier. Why is this error coming?

### UPDATE:

As per one of the valuable comment I have changed the query and the compile error is gone. Now there is an issue in the logic.

```
create or replace procedure proc_tab_count as 
  table_count NUMBER;
  CURSOR total_tables
  IS
     SELECT table_name FROM user_tables; 
BEGIN
  FOR i IN total_tables
  LOOP
SELECT COUNT (*) INTO table_count FROM user_tables WHERE db.table_name = i.table_name; --Wrong logic here
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(i.table_name||'-COUNT:'||table_count);
  END LOOP;
end proc_tab_count;
```

output is coming like:

```
Table1 -COUNT:1
Table2 -COUNT:1
Table3 -COUNT:1
Table3 -COUNT:1
Table4 -COUNT:1
Table5 -COUNT:1
```

Comment: You don't have access to `dba_tables`. Have you tried to access `user_tables` instead? Or to continue with this same code, you will need DBA privilages.

Comment: All you are doing here is iterating over your USER_TABLES and counting rows in USER_TABLES matching the current table name. It will always be 1. You will need to construct some dynamic SQL to count rows in your tables based on USER_TABLES.TABLE_NAME.

Comment: That does not work either, because inside a PL/SQL block you have only privileges which are granted **directly** to the user. Privileges granted through a role do not apply inside a PL/SQL block, i.e. a Procedure or Function (with DEFINER RIGHTS which is the default). So, `GRANT DBA TO MY_USER` does not works, you have to make `GRANT SELECT ANY DICTIONARY TO MY_USER`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess, you want to count rows in all your tables, and we need a *dynamic* `SQL` here.
`EXCEUTE IMMEDIATE` is used to frame the dynamic SQL making the `OWNER.TABLE_NAME` dynamic.

```
create or replace procedure proc_tab_count as 
  table_count NUMBER;
  CURSOR total_tables
  IS
     SELECT table_name FROM user_tables; 
BEGIN
  FOR i IN total_tables
  LOOP
     /* Handle Exceptions */
     BEGIN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT (*)  FROM '|| i.table_name  INTO table_count;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(i.table_name||'-COUNT:'||table_count);
     EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS 
     THEN
             DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error while Querying '||i.table_name||'-Error:'||SQLERRM);
     END;
  END LOOP;
end proc_tab_count;
```

Comment: Thanks. First time I came into `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure that the accepted answer works. Does `user_tables` contain `owner`? Otherwise, it's spot on.

Anyway. Another approach using SYS_REFCURSOR:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_table_count      
  CURSOR total_tables IS
  SELECT table_name 
    FROM user_tables
ORDER BY table_name; 

  table_count NUMBER;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(100);
  v_cursor    SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN total_tables
  LOOP     
     BEGIN
       v_sql := 'SELECT COUNT (*) FROM '||i.table_name;
       OPEN v_cursor FOR v_sql;
       FETCH v_cursor INTO table_count;
       CLOSE v_cursor;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(i.table_name||'-COUNT:'||table_count);
     EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS 
     THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error while Querying '||i.table_name||'-Error:'||SQLERRM);
     END;
  END LOOP;
end proc_tab_count;
```

Comment: The concept was `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` it is ideal for single row returing Queries. Where-as `SYS_REFCURSOR` is something to open a `CURSOR` dynamically, We don't want a `CURSOR` to be opened and closed these many number of times. Also to mention, the CURSOR in `FOR LOOP` had already opened a CURSOR implicitly.! I have a ideal usage of `SYS_REFCURSOR` in the my answere [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631941/use-the-value-of-a-string-variable-in-sql-for-in-select-loop/21632302#21632302). And finally about owner in USER_TABLES, youáre right. I tested using `dba_tables`, and hence it is!

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is to be honest, but I would probably use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` myself in this situation. Just thought I'd throw another solution into the mix.